# Variable Importance results and beyond

Tags: r, predictive-models, caret, importance

This is something I thought sometime ago, forgot about and now remembered.

When using predictive models it is useful to evaluate the relationship between each predictor and the outcome. A very good R-package to do this is [caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/varimp.html).

This is generally called Variable Importance and the importance scores are shown scaled between 0 and 100.

I'd like to know if there is a method where one can look inside each importance score and see which part(s) of the input data contribute the most for reaching the importance score value.

Many thanks.